# Facebook Messenger Bot - mark page threads/messages as read

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-messenger

I have written a Facebook bot that is working well. The app is subscribed to my page and I am getting/sending messages/postbacks just fine. Woo!

Here's the downside - now that we have hundreds of users using the bot, the page "inbox" has become a nightmare.

We still have users that send normal messages to the page, and the bot knows not to respond. However, it's difficult to find those messages as we will have hundreds of unread "messages" or "threads" in the page inbox.

I tried to find a way to mark the items as read after the bot processes them.

The bot has the rights to read all messages for the page, as it sees the non-subscribed messages come in.

I tried using sender_action => mark_seen (which shows the user that the bot has seen the message, but unfortunately does not mark it as read in the inbox). Even when the bot sends the last message (which is normal), it still shows that the thread is unread.

Thanks!

Comment: The way I deal with this is to make a seperate support account that gets messaged by the bot every time someone needs responding to. Then when a staff member goes to respond, they can just message the bot which will then respond to the user without ever having to manually go through and find a conversation

Comment: Good point! That is a good idea, at least until we have the ability to mark threads as read. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FbChatBot mark message as Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710035/fbchatbot-mark-message-as-read)