# FbChatBot mark message as Read

Tags: facebook, chatbot

i am developing fb chat bot, and i want to mark the message as read so that when the moderator of our fb page view the message part, they won't see so many unread messages even though the fb chat bot has already replied that user and they don't need to click that message just to mark it as "read".

How can i achieve this? I am trying to use this API: but it doesn't work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions

Answer (score 2):

You can not mark message as read (as of now), but the best way I deal with this is to use **Handover Protocol**

- When your bot reply the message, it won't appear in INBOX, but it goes to DONE box instead.
- When bot cannot answer, you can let your bot pass thread to INBOX. Then the moderator of page manually answer it. (and mark as DONE afterward)

Follow the instruction here to set it up: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control

(Note: You can pass thread to page inbox and then take thread back immediately. I will notify to INBOX, but your bot can still work with users.)

Comment: Is this new feature of fb bot? Thanks btw! I will try to check this. Is there any side effects in Marking the message as done ???

Comment: Yes, it's a new feature. I think no side effect, all messages will appear as done, until you pass thread to page inbox. When you pass thread to page in box, the bot will not receive webhook, so I did pass and take thread back at the same time to just let it appear in inbox.

Comment: Hey guys this is not working. Any updates to the API of facebook? Where can i send suggestion or for support?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the API you sent here (Facebook's Send API), you **only** mark the message as "seen" from the bot **on the Messenger Chat that you have with your users**. This **doesn't affect the messages inside your Page's inbox**.

Unfortunately, **there is no way** to mark messages as read inside your Page's inbox.

Comment: Any updates? Is there a new update regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this new feature of fb bot? Thanks btw! I will try to check this.
>   Is there any side effects in Marking the message as done ???

To answer your question:

There are some bugs within the ***Inbox***/***Pages Manager*** mobile app. You won't see the messages in **DONE** folder if your admins are using ***Pages Manager*** mobile app for now.

I've reported the issue and working with them to solve it. However, you can still see those messages in **DONE** folder if you use a computer and go into your page's Inbox.

**NOTE:** It seems that messages moved to Inbox will be marked as seen (*not bolded*). This may be a little confusing if your admins don't mark each conversation as **DONE** after admin finishes conversation with the users.