# Reset unread message count for Facebook page (Facebook Graph API)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a small Python tool to connect our Helpdesk software (Helpscout) with our companies Facebook page to be able to receive and answer messages from clients directly from within Helpscout.

I am using the conversation endpoint to grab all unread conversation:

```
    conversations = api.get_object('[page_id]/conversations?fields=messages.limit(20){message,from},name, unread_count,message_count')
```

The problem is, once I read the messages the unread counter still stays the same until we open those messages directly from within the Facebook page. Spent lots of time to find a solution, but apparently there is no option to reset the counter or handle it any other way.

As a workaround I currently use the overall message count and compare it every time I check for new message to only load the new ones. That works fine, but there is still the issue that all messages stay unread on the Facebook page and will be all loaded again with every API call until we manually click them.

Thought about using Selenium to just do this job 1 time per day and clean the inbox, but don't really like this. Any idea how to solve this? Maybe I missed some API feature which can help?

I use the Send API to send the messages back to our customer, but could also not find any option to update the conversation in any way to handle it:

```
data = {"recipient": {"id": "xxxxx"}, "message": {"text": message}}     

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/messages?access_token=xxxx', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Maybe it is possible to move the conversation from the regular inbox to "Done" folder which could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found a solution to it here:
[FbChatBot mark message as Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710035/fbchatbot-mark-message-as-read)

You cannot update the unread count, but you can let all conversations automatically move to the "DONE" folder to let them not show up in your inbox anymore by using the "Handover Protocol": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol

The app has to be set as 'Primary Receiver' and 'Page Inbox' as 'Secondary Receiver'.

[image: Messenger Platform Settings]

All conversations will be moved to "DONE" now. Just make sure to set the correct permissions in the messenger webhook settings:

**[image: App Permissions]**

There will be no error without it, but messages will stay in the inbox and it does not work.